# LG G4 Showing Wrong 'Recovery Mode' Screen

Tags: recovery-mode, custom-roms, boot, lg, lg-g4

I have a LG G4 (International) and I'm trying to boot into recovery to install Lineage OS. The instructions are to hold down the power button and the volume down button, which I do, I then get booted into what apparently is recovery mode but there's no options to do an advanced wipe and clear the cache etc. I found a picture online as to what it boots into:

[image]

As you can see it's still some LG screen, not the actual recovery mode screen you'd expect to see. Am I missing something here?

Comment: [you need to click *yes (for wiping phone), twice*](https://forum.xda-developers.com/g4/help/how-to-enter-recovery-mode-t3267073)

Comment: But if you don't have custom recovery installed, it will wipe your device

Comment: If I select 'yes' it just wipes my phone so that it's back to it's factory default. It doesn't allow me to install a new ROM from .zip. So this screen is the wrong screen.

Comment: @beeshyams So should I install custom recovery? There's noway around it?

Comment: Yes, added that to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to choose and click the *yes* option in your screenshot *twice*:

- If custom recovery is installed, you will boot into it
- If you are on stock recovery , your device is wiped , i.e, factory reset (that's the only option )

See [XDA source](https://forum.xda-developers.com/g4/help/how-to-enter-recovery-mode-t3267073) for more details, including installing custom recovery that gives you the option of advanced wipe and clean cache for flashing custom ROM. Without a custom recovery you can't flash custom ROM

[Here are](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=64148898&postcount=287) instructions for flashing custom recovery

Disclaimer: Never owned LG device, it's Google-fu